# Web Worker Works but generate error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-worker

I created a Web Worker which works correctly but when I open the chrome Console I see the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

This is the file.js which implements the worker.

```
    'use strict';

function GetSummaryAsync() {
    //$.getJSON("/api/Summary/GetSummaryAsync", function (response) {
    //    postMessage(response);
    //});
    postMessage('pippo');
}

GetSummaryAsync();
setInterval(GetSummaryAsync, 15000);
```

Can someone help me to solve the error?

Comment: What’s the problem, the error message already told you in plain English what the issue is - postMessage requires at least two parameters, but you supplied only one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of webworker to add two number, try in similar way

worker.html

```
<html>
<script>
    if (window.Worker){
    
        var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js"); // create a worker object 
        var message = {addData: {num1: 1, num2 :5}};
        myWorker.postMessage(message) // send message to worker
        
        myWorker.onmessage = function(e){
            alert (e.data.result);
        }  // get the response from the worker
    
    }
    else {
        alert("your browser do not support");
    }
</script>
```

*worker.js*

```
this.onmessage = function(e) {
  this.postMessage({result: e.data.addData.num1 + e.data.addData.num1 })  
  // add two number and send to html file
}
```

Comment: Thank you passing an object and not a string the error has been solved :)

Comment: @JonathanLoise It should have no relation to passing String or an object. I guess you have included the worker.js in your HTML, have you? Remove content like <script src="worker.js"></script> from your HTML should solve the issue.

Comment: please.. credit the helper, @prem . Thanks techsith for a simple and crisp example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling method from window object instead of worker (window postMessage needs more arguments). Have you opened it with browser instead of using worker API?

Check
[example how to run and communicate with worker](https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker)